# Reference request: “Sustainable competitive advantage” and "cash holdings"

Tags: reference-request

[**Sustainable competitive advantage**](https://www.arborinvestmentplanner.com/sustainable-competitive-advantages-definition-types-examples/) are company assets, attributes, or abilities that are difficult to duplicate or exceed; and provide a superior or favorable long-term position over competitors.

In [this document](https://www.arborinvestmentplanner.com/sustainable-competitive-advantages-definition-types-examples/), the author said that **Strong Balance Sheet / Cash** is a type of "**Sustainable competitive advantage**"

**Strong Balance Sheet / Cash** is :

> Companies with low debt and/or lots of cash have the flexibility to
> make opportune investments and never have a problem with access to
> working capital, liquidity, or solvency (i.e. Johnson & Johnson
> (JNJ).The balance sheet is the foundation of the company.

I am wondering if there is any peer reviewed paper claiming the same thing?

Comment: What do you mean, ‘official paper’

Comment: I mean, the papers on academic journals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many academic articles documenting the strategic advantage of cash. Two examples that I have read recently are: [Revisiting the concept of a competitive “cash advantage”](https://www.emerald.com/insight/content/doi/10.1108/SL-03-2015-0024/full/html?casa_token=Cn6tL1Azc-IAAAAA:gvHSjNagxbT1nckUbkIOJLukq-ABRafMRLZREZU_KzZRxoZz4lCoz3uToZSUwRvxtXBJHUkxqE3rSrRAcIOgDP_ejZ57zNRn7DimtjyjHNiA72eHiTNO) and [Cash is surprisingly valuable as a strategic asset](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/smj.2205?casa_token=FRqH0HwEStIAAAAA%3AJ6pmccoOVnbJe5kK6TM9K7MZRRL8uq7W7piSYdNqOxoLMuAuVhI7mgnFTsSnvfX1yKzLoLpJ15kV_aw).